# How to send email to the mini-stmp-server?

Tags: ruby, email

I want to use the [mini-stamp-server](https://github.com/aarongough/mini-smtp-server) to build a mail server. I wrote this simple code:

```
require 'mini-smtp-server'                                                      


class StdoutSmtpServer < MiniSmtpServer
    def new_message_event(message_hash)
        puts "#New email received:"
    end
end
server = StdoutSmtpServer.new(2525, "127.0.0.1", 4)

server.start

server.join
```

I don't know how to send mail to the server, e.g., `foo@127.0.0.1:2525` doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the most fundamental way, you can see if your mail server is working by using telnet to connect to it.

Once connected, by doing

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 2525
```

Then typing at the prompt:

```
EHLO your_username
```

This will verify that your mail server is working.

There are several references to troubleshooting SMTP protocol with telnet on the web.

Sending e-mail to it then is as you would any other mail server.